# How should I manage complex logic for setting an initial state of a component?

Tags: reactjs

I want to have an initial state in my component, but I need to set it based on a complex if/else statement.

Using nested tertiarry statements very soon becomes unreadable and unmanageable. And since states should be top-level statements, I can't write if/else statements directly inside the component.

For example, let's say I need to set the initial state for the selected country, based on some given props, from the local storage, from the URL, or from the session state, or from a cookie:

```
const SomeComponent = ({ useUrl, useLocaleStorage, useSessionStorage, useCookie }) => {
    const [initialCountry, setInitialCountry] = useState(/* logic to check where to read from, for the initial state */);

}
```

In the above example, I need to convert this simple JS, to react-style:

```
let initialCountry = 'uk'

if (useUrl) {
   // read from URL and set it
} else if (useCookie) {
   // read from cookie and set it
} else if (useSessionStorage) {
   // read from session storage and set it
} else if (useLocaleStorage) {
   // read from local storage and set it
}
```

I know I can create a simple state, and the use `useEffect` to initialze it. But that makes the state change multiple times. I don't want that. I want the **initial state** to be created using the complex logic, not to be **changed**.

Comment: Hi, did you know that `useState` supports the callback to be passed in? So, you can simplify wrap your logic in function and pass it to the `useState`, it will be called only one as you want it.

Comment: In addition to Ilya Krustalev's suggestion, another option is to use whatever logic you want — if/else, whatever — to compute the initial state value and store it in a local variable, and only then call `useState` with the local variable as its argument. (In your case, since your state variable is called `initialCountry`, I guess its initial value would be `initialInitialCountry`?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question seems quite vague.
But here are some options to consider:

1. If possible use [useMemo](https://react.dev/reference/react/useMemo) instead of `useState`. This will make sure you are only updating the object when needed (if you want you can only initialise once).
2. If you really need the state use a function that calculates your initial state (something like `const [initialCountry, setInitialCountry] = useState(getCountryState());` ). Maybe you can reuse this function to always return you the proper country state if you need to update it (so you can consider extending the functionality to return the updated state if ever needed).
3. If initialising logic looks complex use a [custom hook](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#custom-hooks-sharing-logic-between-components) and, if needed to avoid to much inline code, consider combining this with the function mentioned at point 2
4. This is a standalone recommendation: when possible consider having a constant with the possible values instead of a lot of boolean props.

So instead of using something like

```
const SomeComponent = ({ useUrl, useLocaleStorage, useSessionStorage, useCookie }) => {
  ...
  if (useUrl)...
```

you could have something  like

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  ...
  switch (props.sourceToUse) {
    case SOURCES.url:
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your state you can set the value once:

```
const [data, setData] = useState(yourFunction())

function yourFunction(){
    if(..){
        return ..
    }    
}
```

And if you wanna use useEffect, you can add a 'dependency array':

```
useEffect(() => {}, [dependency])
```

When the dependency changes (and once on start), the useEffect will execute.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to make a single complex expression. `useState` accepts an initializer function, this function is only executed once, when the component is mounted. So this does not only make your code more readable, but probably also faster. Since you don't need to read from cookie/storage and possibly parse JSON for each render.

To quote the [`useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#parameters) documentation:

> - If you pass a function as `initialState`, it will be treated as an *initializer function*. It should be pure, should take no arguments, and should return a value of any type. React will call your initializer function when initializing the component, and store its return value as the initial state. [See an example below.](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#avoiding-recreating-the-initial-state)

```js
const SomeComponent = ({ useUrl, useLocaleStorage, useSessionStorage, useCookie }) => {
    const [initialCountry, setInitialCountry] = useState(() => {
        if (useUrl) return ...;
        if (useCookie) return ...;
        if (useSessionStorage) return ...;
        if (useLocaleStorage) return ...;
    });
}
```